# How to create columns based on string

Tags: python, pandas

| Item | Date |
| --- | --- |
| Bread,Muffin | 1/3 |
| Jam,Cake | 2/3 |
| Jam | 3/3 |

I would like to change to the output below using python / pandas

| Date | Bread | Muffin | Jam | Cake |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/3 | 1 | 1 |  |  |
| 2/3 |  |  | 1 | 1 |
| 3/3 |  |  | 1 |  |

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If need `1` if value exist in column use [`Series.str.get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html):

```
df = df.join(df.pop('Item').str.get_dummies(',').replace(0, ''))
print (df)
  Date Bread Cake Jam Muffin
0  1/3     1               1
1  2/3          1   1       
2  3/3              1
```

If need counts values use [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) with [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) od splitted values by `,`:

```
df1 = df.assign(Item = df['Item'].str.split(',')).explode('Item')

df2 = pd.crosstab(df1['Date'], df1['Item']).replace(0,'').rename_axis(None, axis=1).reset_index()
print (df2)
  Date Bread Cake Jam Muffin
0  1/3     1               1
1  2/3          1   1       
2  3/3              1
```

Difference in changed data:

```
print (df)
                 Item Date
0  Bread,Muffin,Bread  1/3 <- duplicated Bread
1            Jam,Cake  2/3
2                 Jam  3/3

df1 = df.assign(Item = df['Item'].str.split(',')).explode('Item')

df2 = pd.crosstab(df1['Date'], df1['Item']).replace(0,'').rename_axis(None, axis=1).reset_index()
print (df2)
  Date Bread Cake Jam Muffin
0  1/3     2               1
1  2/3          1   1       
2  3/3              1       

df0 = df.join(df.pop('Item').str.get_dummies(',').replace(0, ''))
print (df0)
  Date Bread Cake Jam Muffin
0  1/3     1               1
1  2/3          1   1       
2  3/3              1
```